# Azure VM crashed and I recovered the VHD however cloud-init prevents me from booting it locally

Tags: linux, hyper-v, azure, vhd, cloud-init

One of our VM's suddenly was stuck at 100% CPU load and was unable to be reached from SSH. Rebooting did not help, nor did creating a new VM from the existing VHD.

I downloaded the VHD. However, I'm unable to boot it since it gets stuck on cloud-init looking for a way to login (I presume). Is there any way to circumvent the cloud-init process and let me somehow log in?

```
cloud-init-nonet waiting 120 seconds for a network device.
cloud-init-nonet gave up waiting for a network device.
...
route_init failed
```

Comment: Don't know how to fix the cloud-init problem, but since this is a VHD file, you can mount it into a Windows machine and browse it as if its a local disk, maybe this will help you into disabling the cloud-init service?

Answer (score 0):

Create a VM with a functional image as the first VHD and the problematic image as the second VHD. Then you should be able to use this new VM to look at the files you need to on the second VHD as well as making changes needed in order to boot it.

Once you have made changes shut down this VM and try to boot the modified image on its own.